# jQuery: checked value from variable name or $(this)

Tags: jquery, checkbox, checked

If I have some radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="test" value="apple"> Apple<br/>
<input type="radio" name="test" value="banana" CHECKED> Banana<br/>
<input type="radio" name="test" value="carrot"> Carrot<br/>
```

and I then define the radio group in jQuery with

```
var test = $('input:radio[name="test"]')
```

How can I get the value of the checked element based on the variable test without re-writing

```
var test_val = $('input:radio[name="test"]:checked').val();
```

I've tried both

```
$(test):checked.val();
test:checked.val();
```

And as part of a change function I've also tried this:

```
$(test).change(function() {
    if ($(this):checked.val() == 'no') {
        $('#featured').stop().fadeOut();
    } else if ($(this):checked.val() == 'yes') {
        $('#featured').stop().fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Just wondering if this is possible or if I have to re-write out the full input selector to get the value.

**P.S.**
If IE8 doesn't support the `:checked` selector, what can I use instead?

Comment: No browser supports `:checked` the way you use it. It is invalid JS syntax. A selector is always in a string. There are some methods which have the same effect as a selector, but they are called just like normal methods.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `.filter()`<sup>[help](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)</sup>:

```
test.filter('input:checked')
```

`.filter()` does also support a callback:

```
test.filter(function() {
    return this.name === 'test' && this.checked
});
```

I wasn't aware that the `:checked` selector does not work with IE8. If that is true, the latter example should work (accessing the node expando directly)

Comment: And I think the OP only concluded that `:checked` does not work in IE8 because the syntax he/she used does not work. jQuery will definitely make sure that it works in all browsers.

Comment: @FelixKling - I thought I read that somewhere.  Can I presume it is incorrect and :checked does work in IE?  My broken syntax wasn't working in any browser.

Comment: @helgatheviking: yes, `.filter('input:checked')` does work cross-browser.

Comment: @helgatheviking: Well I can only assume as jQuery claims to be cross-browser compatible, that every aspect of jQuery works in every browser. Also the documentation does not mention any issue with IE.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to mix "CSS syntax" with JavaScript syntax. That won't work.

You can use jQuery's `filter()` method to limit the elements selected with a previous jQuery query:

```
var test = $('input:radio[name="test"]')

var test_val = test.filter(":checked").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
$(test).change(function() {
 if ($(this).is(':checked').val() == 'no'){
   $('#featured').stop().fadeOut();
 } else if ($(this).is(':checked').val() == 'yes'){
  $('#featured').stop().fadeIn();
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Startibg from `var test`, you can use the .filter() function, as shown in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WNUFb/)

```
var test = $('input:radio[name="test"]');
alert(test.filter(':checked').val());
```